# Facebook API: How to let the php knows whether the user is a fan of the application or not?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

Facebook API: How to let the php knows whether the user is a fan of the application or not?

Plan 1: failed
 is displayed at the html level only.. .it won't let the php level knows whether the user is a fan or not

Plan 2: failed
 has got the same problem too

Plan 3: failed
fql permission table simply lacked the field of is_fan
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Permissions_%28FQL%29

Plan 4: server lag
calling restful API http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Pages.isFan will bring a lot of lag to server... and I wonder if it can works on application page too.

any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I have found the solution

$ispagefan = $facebook->api_client->pages_isFan($app_id,$fb_user);

X( spending hours before posting here and still can't get the solution. Then found a solution right after posting this